# How to Parse / Decode php encoded JSON output using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, decode

I need to decode JSON encoded data of php in JavaScript.
I am giving php code below:

```
 $emparray = array();
        //$column_filter_text = $_POST['column_filter_text'];
        $result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT " . $something . " FROM wpgw_wpdatatable_1");
        if($result){
            //echo json_encode($result);
             foreach ( $result as $row )
{
   $emparray[] = $row;
}
            echo json_encode($emparray);
        }
The output of this php code:
[{"BMC":null},{"BMC":"BRICK MASONRY"},{"BMC":"STONES"},{"BMC":"TIMBER"},{"BMC":"CEMENT"},{"BMC":"CONCRETE"},{"BMC":"BRICKS"},{"BMC":"STEEL"},{"BMC":"CERAMIC"},{"BMC":"PAINTS \/ VARNISHES"},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null},{"BMC":null}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Yeah but to implement coding? How to retrieve the data using Javascript?

Comment: This is an other question. If you're using PHP to create the page you could write something like that `echo '<script>const emparray = JSON.parse(' . json_encode($emparray) . ')</script>';` otherwise you could use `fetch`